# How to use apply to create multiple polynomial variables?

Tags: r, polynomial-math, feature-engineering

I have several variables,

```
qual_cols <- c("ExterQual", "ExterCond", "BsmtQual", "BsmtCond", "HeatingQC", "KitchenQual", "FireplaceQu", "GarageQual", "GarageCond", "PoolQC")
```

each column composed of the same five chr values:

```
grades <- c( "Po", "Fa", "TA", "Gd", "Ex")
```

which I would like to numericize

```
"Po" = 1; "Fa" = 2; "TA" = 4  "Gd" = 6 "Ex" = 11
```

in order to multiply to create new variables, like these:

```
combi$GarageGrade <- combi$GarageQual * combi$GarageCond
combi$ExterGrade <- combi$ExterQual * combi$ExterCond
combi$KitchenScore <- combi$KitchenAbvGr * combi$KitchenQual
```

What are some ways to achieve this?

Note: I am a beginner in programming, so overstating the obvious is appreciated.

Example:

```
head(combi$ExterQual) # (Gd, TA, Gd, TA, Gd, Ta)
```

value-equivalents would be (6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4)

```
head(combi$ExterCond) # (TA, TA, TA, TA, TA, TA)
```

value-equivalents would be (4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)

```
combi$ExterGrade <- combi$ExterQual * combi$ExterCond
head(combi$ExterGrade) # expected output: (24, 16, 24, 16, 24, 16)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Hi @akrun updated, let me know if it could use any further clarification

Comment: Have a doubt, how are these columns `"BsmtCond"    "HeatingQC"` multiplied as some of the names in `qual_cols` doesn't have a corresponding 'Qual/Cond' column

Comment: Those are multiplied by columns that are already numeric

Comment: Please check your `qual_cols`.  I don't find a pattern for some column multiplication.  Anyway, based on the info you gave, I posted a solution

Comment: Thank you! I see it below! I am getting errors but it's possible I didn't ask my question the best way. I will ask a mentor to help me implement your code and let you know how it goes! I put it here for now https://github.com/annieeby/Capstone-House-Prices/blob/master/Polynomial%20Variable%20Generation.R

Comment: Or the full code here: https://github.com/annieeby/Capstone-House-Prices/blob/master/house.R not sure if it's considered useful to just post the actual code in general

Comment: Based on your description, I created the data and it is working fine for me

Comment: Hi @akrun thanks I see what you mean now; you combined all steps in to one. You are totally right, it works!

Comment: In an effort to simplify my question, I did not include the fact that I was multiply more than just "Qual"/"Cond" variables. This was my fault for not showing all use-cases of the code! I posted another possible method below. Thank you so much @akrun !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of a named vector to change the values to numeric

```
newdata <- combi[qual_cols]
newdata[] <- lapply(combi[qual_cols], function(x) 
         setNames(c(1, 2, 4, 6, 11), grades)[x])
nm1 <- grep("(Cond|Qual)$", names(newdata), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- sub("[A-Z][a-z]+$", "", nm1)
nm3 <- paste0(unique(nm2), 'Grade')
newdata[nm3] <- lapply(split.default(newdata[nm1], nm2), function(x) Reduce(`*`, x))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
combi <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(grades, 10 * 5, replace = TRUE), 
   ncol = 10, dimnames = list(NULL, qual_cols)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If variable names are not consistent (i.e. not just Qual and Cond), this is a more flexible approach:

## Identify variables with Po, Fa, TA, Gd, Ex values

```
qual_cols <- c("ExterQual", "ExterCond", "BsmtQual", "BsmtCond", "HeatingQC", "KitchenQual", "FireplaceQu", "GarageQual", "GarageCond", "PoolQC")
```

## Replace grade categories with numeric values.

```
numeric_quals = sapply(combi[qual_cols], function(x) ifelse(x == 'Po', 1, 
                                        ifelse(x =='Fa', 2,
                                        ifelse(x =='TA', 4,
                                        ifelse(x == 'Gd', 6,
                                        ifelse(x == 'Ex', 11, 0))))) )
```

## Replace (altered) variables in dataframe.

```
combi = combi %>% select(-qual_cols) %>% cbind(numeric_quals)
```

## Perform multiplication

Overall quality of the house

```
combi$OverallGrade <- combi$OverallQual * combi$OverallCond
head(combi$OverallGrade)
```

Overall pool score

```
combi$PoolScore <- combi$PoolArea * combi$PoolQC
```

Overall Garage size

```
combi$AllGarage <- combi$GarageCars * combi$GarageArea
```

Total number of bathrooms

```
combi$TotalBath <- combi$BsmtFullBath + (0.5 * combi$BsmtHalfBath) + 
  combi$FullBath + (0.5 * combi$HalfBath)
```

Total finished SF for house (incl. basement)

```
combi$AllSF <- combi$GrLivArea + combi$TotalBsmtSF
```

Total SF for porch

```
combi$AllPorchSF <- combi$OpenPorchSF + combi$EnclosedPorch + 
  combi$X3SsnPorch + combi$ScreenPorch
```

Combined additions

```
combi$Additions <- combi$YearRemodAdd + as.numeric(combi$GarageYrBlt)
```